# What is the return type of Class<?>#getTypeParameters()?

Tags: java, class, generics, type-variables

With a given [`java.lang.reflect.Method`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html).

I can call,

```java
final Class<?> returnType = method.getReturnType();
```

But when I tried to call [`getTypeParameters()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getTypeParameters%28%29) with following statement,

```java
final TypeVariable<Class<?>>[] typeParameters = returnType.getTypeParameters();
```

I got a compiler error.

```
required: java.lang.reflect.TypeVariable<java.lang.Class<?>>[]
found:    java.lang.reflect.TypeVariable<java.lang.Class<capture#1 of ?>>[]
```

What's wrong this statement? I just followed apidocs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the code is attempting to perform a safe operation.

Helper method needs to be created so that the wildcard can be captured through type inference.
compiler is not able to confirm the type of object that is being inserted into the list, and an error is produced. When this type of error occurs it typically means that the compiler believes that you are assigning the wrong type to a variable. Generics were added to the Java language for this reason — to enforce type safety at compile time.

here is the java doc refrence that explains the same.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/capture.html

while this will work

```
final TypeVariable<?>[] typeParameters =returnType.getTypeParameters();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try

```
final Class<?> returnType = method.getReturnType();
final TypeVariable<?>[] typeParameters =  returnType.getTypeParameters();  
if (types.length > 0){  
   // do something with every type...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you need, you could also use

```
final TypeVariable<? extends Class<?>>[] typeParameters = returnType.getTypeParameters();
```